# Is there any input / output to the local device?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Are there external objects or functions that can be read and written to the local device as an alternative to ClientStorage in an online application?
I want to use it as an alternative to WebSession.

Comment: In SD you can also use the websession. In any case, as you said, the EO ClientStorage would be the alternative in this case, and it works for both online and offline apps. Maybe if you tell us a little more about what you're traying to do we could help you with a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you using "file" datatype?  this is just my opinion.

```
Event 'write'
    //&tempstring is Character(999), &tempstrings is  Character(999) and collection
    &file.Source = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &file.Separator + "myFile.txt"
    &tempstrings.Clear()
    &tempstrings.Add(&tempstring)
    &file.AppendAllLines(&tempstrings)
Endevent

Event 'read'
    &file.Source = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &file.Separator + "myFile.txt"
    &tempstring = &file.ReadAllText()

Endevent
```